# efficient way of inserting data in MySql from C# code with inner foreach

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two **DataTables**

```
DataTable dtDataForTransactions;
DataTable dtDataForTransline;
```

in my C# code. `dtDataForTransline` can have single or multiple records against any transaction in `dtDataForTransactions`. For example

**dtDataForTransactions**

```
transid | ticketid | storeid | TIMESTAMP   | transtypeid | total
----------------------------------------------------------------
A-101   | 101      | 1       | 20018-03-23 | 1           |60.00
A-102   | 102      | 1       | 20018-03-23 | 1           |30.25
A-103   | 103      | 1       | 20018-03-23 | 1           |75.50
```

**dtDataForTransline**

```
transid | productid | qty | price   
---------------------------------
A-101   | 1000001   | 1   |60.00 // single trnsline against transaction
// two entry against one A-102 transaction
A-102   | 1054141   | 1   |20.25 
A-102   | 5421441   | 2   |10.00 
// three entries for A-103 transaction
A-103   | 1088888   | 1   |20.50
A-103   | 5435415   | 3   |15.00
A-103   | 9921441   | 6   |40.00
```

I am using transaction to roll if something happen un-expected. My current way of inserting data takes long time (say 15 seconds for 5 records in transactions table and 15 records in transline).

how can I make it efficient, my MySql database in cloud-base and I am hitting this call from local machine.

**My Code:**

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionMySql))
            {
                con.Open();
                foreach (DataRow row in dtDataForTransactions.Rows)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        tr = con.BeginTransaction();

                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

                        cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO transaction (transid, ticketid, storeid, TIMESTAMP, transtypeid, total) Values (@transid, @ticketid, @storeid, @timestamp, @transtypeid, @total)", con, tr);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@transid", row["transid"])).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@ticketid", row["ticketid"])).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@storeid", row["storeid"])).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@timestamp", row["TIMESTAMP1"])).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.DateTime;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@transtypeid", row["transtypeid"])).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@total", row["total"])).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Float;                       

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        DataTable dtTemp = dtDataForTransline.AsEnumerable().
                                           Where(s => s.Field<string>("transid") == row["transid"].ToString()).CopyToDataTable();



                        foreach (DataRow row2 in dtTemp.Rows)
                        {
                            cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO transline (transid,productid,qty,price) values (@transid, @productid, @qty, @price)", con, tr);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@transid", row2["transid"])).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@productid", row2["barcode"])).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@qty", row2["qty"])).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Double;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@price", row2["price"])).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Decimal;
                            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@transid1", row["transid"])).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                            

                        }
                        tr.Commit();
                        cmd.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        tr.Rollback();                        
                        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
                        break;
                    }
     }
```

Comment: What is taking long? Is it `Commit()` (Might be sql problem) or is it `ExecuteNonQuery()` (Network connection setup problem, try bulk insertion techniques)

Comment: @mjwills done with indentation

Comment: @Tewr I did not notice that, I thing in `Commit()` which is being called multiple times in foreach

Comment: You should wrap the MysqlCommand is `using` also then it disposes it properly, also move the `commit` outside the foreach.

Comment: You *think* it's Commit()? If you are not sure what is taking long, [measure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)!

Comment: @KayNelson: I can only guess at the business domain, but the naming of his tables hints that functionally, the transaction should probably remain inside the foreach. Should still be in a `using` though.

Comment: @KayNelson I am saving every entry which is inserted in db to my local file. that is why commit cannot be outside the loop

Comment: Can any one suggest SQKBulk here